# How to modify plotly axis start position?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using

python3.7.6
plotly==4.9.0

trying to modify the x-range of a chart like

[image: orginal picture]

to fully use the space, like the following picture. X start from the first point without any margin
[image: modified]

I can do this with

```py
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3]

fig=px.line(x,y)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={
        'range':[0.99,3]
    })
```

But if I have a categorical axis,

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'x':['xx','yy','zz'],
    'y':[1,2,3]})

fig=px.bar(df,x,y)
```

how can I set the range of axis?

Thanks

Comment: I still don't really know what I want to do. Do you want to draw `px.line` and `px.bar` in one graph and set it to the origin (0,0)? Before that, `fig.=px.bar(df,'x','y')` is the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

For categorical axes the range works the same as numerical, in this case the category is converted to an integer, see [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-range) and below (emphasis added).

> Sets the range of this axis. If the axis `type` is "log", then you
> must take the log of your desired range (e.g. to set the range from 1
> to 100, set the range from 0 to 2). If the axis `type` is "date", it
> should be date strings, like date data, though Date objects and unix
> milliseconds will be accepted and converted to strings. **If the axis
> `type` is "category", it should be numbers, using the scale where each
> category is assigned a serial number from zero in the order it
> appears.**

For your example try:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.DataFrame({
    'x':['xx','yy','zz'],
    'y':[1,2,3]})

fig=px.bar(df,x='x',y='y')

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={
        'range':[-.4,2.4]
    })

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! simple answer does helps :D